# How do you add value to only y coordinates in a list?

Tags: python, list, math, coordinates

I'm currently doing a school project where I need to code a program in python that subtracts a value from a list of coordinates.
I'm not allowed to use `import` to make things easier.

I have the list: `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`
and I need to subtract a value from the second value in each list inside this list.

So for an example: `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`
becomes: `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`

This is the code I have thus far:

```
def coordinates(y):
    for i in (y):
        (i[1] - 5)
        return (y)
```

I just can't get it to work though. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Edit:

ShyGuyRyRyNewlyTheDataGuy's code worked like a charm if anyone has the same problem!

```
def coordinates(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i][1] = l[i][1] - 1
    return l
```

Comment: if it was working, undelete it and wait maybe others will upvote it. nobody can be forced to comment if he votes

Comment: if you only want to help, why do oyu care abput votes. like i said undelete it

Comment: `return` immediately exits the function, so your loop is only running through the first iteration. Instead, `append` your loop output to a list, then `return` the list at the end

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that *(i[1] - 5)* effectively does nothing as you're not assigning the result of that computation to anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you're attempting to always subtract from the y coordinate, indexing into the list's set of lists would provide the easiest solution to your problem.

The following subtracts 1 from the lists second coordinate and returns the list.

```
def coordinates(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i][1] = l[i][1] - 1
    return l
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you don't want to modify the original list. In that case:

```
def coordinates(l, n=1):
    return [[x, y-n] for x, y in l]

print(coordinates([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your function generic by passing everything it needs to know to is as arguments instead of hardcoding everythings into it — which will allow it to be reused with different lists and/or amounts.

This following illustrates what I mean:

```
def add_y(coords, y):
    for coord in coords:
        coord[1] += y
    return coords

data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]

print(data)  # -> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
data = add_y(data, -1)
print(data)  # -> [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coordinate = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]

def coordinates(y):

    new_list = [ ]
    for i in (y):
        new_list += [[i[0],i[1]-1]]
    print (new_list)

coordinates(coordinate)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.